After hook destructuring issue
I have created a playwright-bdd framework using typescript where it updates the Jira x-ray test case to pass/fail  based on the execution.
Below is my After hook
After(async ({ $testInfo }: { $testInfo: TestInfo }) => {
        let found = false;
        const status = $testInfo.status === 'failed' ? 'FAILED' : 'PASSED';
        console.log("Status:", status);
        for (const execution of testMappings) {
            // Check each test case within the current execution entry
            for (const testCase of execution.testCases) {
                const annotations = $testInfo.annotations;
                let uri;
                annotations.forEach(annotation => {
                    if (annotation.type === '__bddData') {
                        // Parse the description field to a JavaScript object
                        const bddData = JSON.parse(annotation.description);
            
                        // Access and log the uri
                        uri = bddData.uri;
                        console.log("URI:", uri);
                    }
                });
                // Adjust matching logic if necessary
                if (testCase.playwrightTestId === uri ||       testCase.playwrightTestId.endsWith(path.basename(uri))) {
                    found = true;
                    const status = $testInfo.status === 'failed' ? 'FAILED' : 'PASSED';
                    await updateStatus(testCase.xrayTestId, execution.testExecution, status, $testInfo.error?.message || '');
                }
            }
        }
        // Perform any necessary cleanup here
    });

I get below error when I execute npx bddgen command
   throw new Error(`
    `^`
    `Error: First argument must use the object destructuring pattern: _a function (_a) { return    __awaiter(void 0, [_a], void 0, function (_b) {`
    `var $testInfo = _b.$testInfo;`
    `return __generator(this, function (_c) {`
    `console.log("Test Status:", $testInfo.status);`
    `return [2 /`*`return`*`/];`
    `});`
    `}); }

npx bddgen command works if I don't have any parameter in the After hook.
Please help me resolve this issue.
I want to get the status of the test execution. For that I am using { $testInfo } within After hook
